# How to reset the git-flow configuration in SourceTree?

Tags: git, git-flow, atlassian-sourcetree

In my team we are migrating from svn to git and we have agreed upon embracing the git-flow flow. I've been playing around a while with SourceTree and the Git-Flow extension. Now, we have decided that the develop branch will be called development/current instead, but I do not find in the SourceTree UI where to change the Git-Flow configuration.

Is it possible, once initialized, to change the Git-Flow configuration for a given repository?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

No, it is not possible (at least not at SourceTree 1.4.1.0).

It is possible however to do it manually by editing the file `/.git/config` in your git repository.

The Git-Flow extension adds it s configuration in the following two sections, which can be freely edited.

```
[gitflow "branch"]
    master = master
    develop = development/current
[gitflow "prefix"]
    feature = feature/
    release = release/
    hotfix = hotfix/
    versiontag = release/
    support = support/
```

Resource: [http://www.crisi.ch/change-git-flow-settings-in-sourcetree/](https://web.archive.org/web/20151005091840/http://www.crisi.ch/change-git-flow-settings-in-sourcetree/)

Answer (score 52):

In SourceTree 2.x it is easy to edit your GitFlow.

1. Click Settings if you're using Mac (Repository - Repository Settings in Windows)
2. Select Advanced Tab
3. Click Edit Config File ...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @RyuX51, a picture is worth a thousand words, no doubts

Answer (score 12):

You have to use `git flow init -f`

Comment: What's the `-f` flag used for?

Comment: @Jonjie it means `force`

Comment: @CrsCaballero Nice, thanks for your fast response man.